# plupload upload files with a size larger than about 4 GB

Tags: plupload

I am using plupload (1.5.4) on a website to upload movie files.
If I try to add a file with size of 4287360 kB, the file is simply not added to the upload queue.

The problem seems to be on the client side, since I have not yet pressed the "Start upload" button, but only the "Add files" button.

The runtime selected by plupload when running in the current version of Firefox is flash.

Here is the php setup code:

```
$("#uploaderdiv").plupload({
    runtimes : 'flash,html5,browserplus,silverlight,gears,html4',
    max_file_size : '20000mb',
    max_file_count : 1, // user can add no more then 1 file at a time
    chunk_size : '4mb',
    url : 'plupload_1_5_4/plupload/examples/upload.php',
    flash_swf_url : 'js/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
unique_names : false,
    multiple_queues : true,
    filters : [
    ],
  });
```

What must I do to allow users to upload files up to 15 or 20 GiB in size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the limitation was caused by the plupload flash engine in this line:

```
runtimes : 'flash,html5,browserplus,silverlight,gears,html4',
```

When I changed this engine priority list to:

```
runtimes : 'html5,browserplus,silverlight,flash,gears,html4',
```

I could also queue and upload larger files, as tested with a 19 GB file using the html5 engine.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Flash platform (Flash itself) is limited to 2 GB, because of 32-bit integer limitation. If you plan to upload larger files you should _remove_, (not _reorder_) `flash` platform from your `runtimes` string.